# Background color changes in render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

I am having an issue with my render.
I have set a plane to the background with white emmission color. In the viewport everything is as i want it to but when I hit render the background becomes dark (First image is screen of my viewport and the second one is the render). Any ideas what the issue could be? The same thing is happening in Cycles and Eevee.

[image: Screen of my vieport]

[image: render]

Comment: Make sure the option hide in renders option is not ticked in the object properties panel under visibility.

Comment: OMG! I am such a fool. Thats it, thank you!

Comment: You're Welcome! (: